# how to add click only on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, buttonclick

I am using jquery to bind a click on a button. In this var testId i am getting the id of the button and var showmoreId is getting the id of a div but the problem is onclick binds with the li so when i click anywhere in li onclick is working but i want it to work on button click and i also want the id of the div on click but do not want li to work on click so what  can i do to fix it.

```
async function userData(userdata) {
    let newValue = ""; 

userdata.forEach(max=> { 
let add =  `<div class="rb-container">
            <ul class="rb">
            <li>
            <div>
            <p>${max.name}</p>
    
            <div>
            <p>${max.email}</p>
            <button id="showMoreLess_${max.id}" data-order-id="${max.id}">View More</button>
            </div>
                
            <div id="showme_${max.id}" class="showBlock" style="display:none";>
    
            <div>
            <div>
            <p>Quantity:</p>
            <p>${max.volume}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
            <p>${max.group_email}</p>
            <p>Group_Email</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
            </li>
</ul>
</div>`


 newValue += add ;
 let container = document.querySelector('.user-details');
    container.innerHTML = newValue;

}

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.rb-container li').unbind('click');

        $('.rb-container li').on('click', function () { 
            var testId = $(this).find('button').attr('id');          
            var showmoreId = ($(this).find('div > div').next().attr('id'));
            
            viewFullDetails(testId, showmoreId);
        });
```

Comment: If you don't want the click on the `li` then don't bind it to the `li`: `$('.rb-container li').on('click'` -> `$('.rb-container li button').on('click'` - I'm not entirely sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The `.on()` function supports an optional selector to handle events on certain child elements.

```
    $('.rb-container li').on('click', 'button', function() {
        var testId = $(this).attr('id');
        var showmoreId = $(this).closest('li').find('div > div').next().attr('id');
        
        viewFullDetails(testId, showmoreId);
    });
```

Note that I just added the selector `'button'` but of course you can use any selector, e.g. `#id`. I then found the closest `li` to go from there to get the `showmoreId`.

Please also consider to use `.off()` instead of `.unbind()` as the latter has been deprecated.

Comment: i want the id of the button and div id on click and id is different as i am appending max.id with id(css)  so i can add a function but click functionality should work on button click

Comment: I updated it, so it now gets the proper ids, as `$(this)` is now referring to the button.
Not sure if you were aiming for that with your comment, though.